# Migration from SQL Server 2000 to SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2000

HI can any one help in this as I need to migrate from SQL Server 2000 to SQL Server 2005 in which I need to check databases that are no longer active and deprecated features to determine for compatibility 65 databases if there are any deprecated features running which may cause an issue when we migrate databases to SQL Server 2005 instance

Please help me in this

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft have a tool that can scan 7.0 and 2000 databases and provide advice on such problems. It's called the [SQL Server 2005 Upgrade Advisor](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=1470E86B-7E05-4322-A677-95AB44F12D75).

I'm not sure how well it will do against databases on a 2000 instance set to 65 compatibility however. You might have to migrate them to 70 or 80 compatibility first.

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510680.aspx

The link above lists the differences between the SQL compatibility levels, might be useful for you, be sure to check to the section titled **Differences Between Lower Compatibility Levels and Level 100**